# How to display data from 3 tables using Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have 3 tables in my database and these are their EF models:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactID { get; set; }
    public string VehicleID { get; set; }
    public IList<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }      
    public IList<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}
public class Vehicle
{
   [Key]
   public string VehicleID {get; set;}
   public string Make {get; set;}
}

public class Contact
{
   [Key]
   public string ContactID {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The db context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Customer>().HasKey(q => new { q.ContactID, q.VehicleID });
         }
        //Defining entities for context class
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

In my controller:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {

            return _context.Customer.Include(c => c.Contacts).Include(v => v.Vehicles);
                
        }
```

My goal is to return data from the three tables but when I run this I get the error: SqlException: Invalid column name CustomerContactID
CustomerVehicleID

Any help appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework - Invalid Column Name '\*\_ID"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959256/entity-framework-invalid-column-name-id)

Comment: I am using IList not I Collections

Comment: mine still working. I use IList also. you need to find where are CustomerContactID and CustomerVehicleID in. they are not found in your model. you need to check database too.

Comment: You should look into ViewModels where you flatten things out in the controller, send it to the view in a friendly manner, return it to the controller and update the entity(s). A tool like Automapper makes this easy. Now you can separate the concerns of entities versus what you want for the view. See [here](https://wildermuth.com/2015/07/22/Mapping_Between_Entities_and_View_Models).

Comment: You can create a dto class with your final view then query all the data within this model. You can use your context object multiple times to get data from different tables.